Anime where the main character can fuse with spirits
I had watch an anime couple of years ago which the mc can fuse with spirits. It all starts I think it's a mountain with his best friend and without knowing this best friend of his is a spirit and also when he's fuses with it he can use bow. Additionally his best friend is a water element. They began their journey together and I think the second spirit he met is a woman with fire element. They go on a journey together to find the other spirits with other elements.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I tried to make sentences, but some of it is still unclear.  When and where did you watch this?

Not an exact fit, but maybe Black Clover, a manga that's been running since 2015, with an anime adaptation that aired between 2017 and 2021?
The main characters are Asta, a boy without any magic power who gains anti-magic abilities, and his friend Yuno, who has enormous wind-based magic power. Yuno can make bows (Though I believe he prefers swords), and meets the spirit Sylph, who he can fuse with to get even more power and a fairy-like appearance as a side effect. Fusing with spirits happens with other characters too, and magic tends to be elemental.
